# Passing object to function within a class

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

I'm wondering how I can pass an object that has been set elsewhere between functions within a class? EDIT: *So that the function only uses the default values if they have not been set.*

So for example below I have in the construct function the default parameters in the object objAuthParams. If I want to call the class and change these params I know I can do this by creating a new class but in that instance how would I pass the new values to the function *oauthorise*?

I have spent a good amount of time searching the web but as you can probably tell I am not able to articulate what I am trying to do very well and I am very rusty with PHP would greatly appreciate any pointers/explainations of where I am going wrong!

Here's the code

```
class oauth {

public $objAuthParams;


// Construnct
public function __construct() {
$this->objAuthParams = (object) array(
        "method" => "GET",
        "access_token" => "a token",
        "access_token_secret" => "a secret",
        "consumer_key" => "b consumer",
        "consumer_secret" => "b secret"     
);  

$this->oauthorise();
}


public function oauthorise() {

echo $this->objAuthParams->method; 

}       


} // eoc


// Attempt to set new params for method
$class = new oauth;

$class->objAuthParams->method = "im a hairy badger";
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your concern is. `oauthorise()` will echo whatever that object's `method` property holds currently. So when you do `new oauth;`, the constructor calls `oauthorise()` once and at this point, `method` is "GET". Then you change it, so if you call `$class->oauthorise()` again, it should now echo "im a hairy badger".

Comment: Ahh can't see the wood for the trees. I suppose the solution I was aiming for was setting the method before running the constructor so that if the value was unset it used the defaults and if it is set that overrides the defaults, I could do this with some conditional statements but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass in the `objAuthParams` object into the constructor.  If that is set then set your `$onjAuthParam` variable to the one injected.

```
<?php

class oauth {

    public $objAuthParams;

    // Construnct
    public function __construct($objAuthParams = false) {
        if(!$objAuthParams)
            $this->objAuthParams = (object) array(
                "method" => "GET",
                "access_token" => "a token",
                "access_token_secret" => "a secret",
                "consumer_key" => "b consumer",
                "consumer_secret" => "b secret"     
            );
        else 
            $this->objAuthParams = $objAuthParams;

        $this->oauthorise();
    }


    public function oauthorise() {
        echo $this->objAuthParams->method; 
    }       


}

$myAuthParams = (object)array(
    "method" => "im a hairy badger",
    "access_token" => "a token",
    "access_token_secret" => "a secret",
    "consumer_key" => "b consumer",
    "consumer_secret" => "b secret"  
);

$class = new oauth($myAuthParams);
print_r($class); 

$class2 = new oauth();
print_r($class2)
```

This is referred to dependancy injection. -- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/dependency-injection-in-php/

Comment: You need to add a format check. If you pass a $myAuthParams array with different keys than the class expects (could be just a typo for example), currently that would go unnoticed and you would have errors further down the program where you're trying to use the keys.

Comment: or better still define a class for AuthParams.